# How to re-size an image keeping there aspect ratio and upload it

Tags: php, image, image-resizing, aspect-ratio

I have a button which uploads a background image to a folder and saves the file name to the database, but I cant figure how to re size the image before uploading it. Actually I am facing two problems.
1 - How to resize the image and upload it.
2 - How to display the image as background image for a div which is having a different dimension.

What I have done till now :

**Html**

```
<div class="image_load_div">
 <form id="imageform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
   <input name="photoimg" id="photoimg" type="file"/>
 </form>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$("#imageform").ajaxForm().submit();
```

**php - upload file**

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
   name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
   $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
   if(strlen($name)) {
 list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
 if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
   if($size<(1024*1024)) {
          session_start();
      $id = $_SESSION['QuestionId'];
      $path = "/images/Img/".$id."_bg.".$ext;

          if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photoimg"]["tmp_name"],$path) ) {
             // Save the file name into database
          }
        else { echo "<script>alert('Upload failed');</script>"; }
   else { echo "<script>alert('Image file size max 1 MB');</script>"; }                 
    else {  echo "<script>alert('Invalid file format..');</script>"; }  
 else { echo "<script>alert('Please select image..!');</script>";   exit; }
```

I would like to save the image as height:408px; width:490px;
and when displaying the image I want to display this image width:174px; height:108px;
***IMP !During uploading and when displaying, need to consider the aspect ratio;***
for now uploading is working.

please help me to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working and well tested code. Hope it will work for you.

Calling methode:

```
$newname="xyz";
$filename=$_FILES['featured-img']['name'];
$extension=strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1)); //Get extension
$extension=trim($extension);
$newfilename=$newname.$extension;
$newfilename=preg_replace('/\s+/', '_',$newfilename);

$target1 = "directory_path".$newfilename;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['featured-img']['tmp_name'],$target1));   
scaleImage($target1,500, 350, $target1);
```

Method defination:

```
function scaleImage($source_image_path, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $thumbnail_image_path){


          list($source_image_width, $source_image_height, $source_image_type) = getimagesize($source_image_path);
    switch ($source_image_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_image_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_image_path);
            break;
    }
    if ($source_gd_image === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $thumbnail_image_width=$maxWidth;
    $thumbnail_image_height=$maxHeight;


    $thumbnail_gd_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_image_width, $thumbnail_image_height);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbnail_gd_image, $source_gd_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbnail_image_width, $thumbnail_image_height, $source_image_width, $source_image_height);
    imagejpeg($thumbnail_gd_image, $thumbnail_image_path, 90);
    imagedestroy($source_gd_image);
    imagedestroy($thumbnail_gd_image);
    return true;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for this, and still keep the proportions.

```
<img src="image.png" style="max-width: 400px;">
```

Then you could use php to make a smaller size of the the image as a *catch all* maximum size,then use CSS to fine tune the size of it